# Faceted time series data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a faceted plot of two variables, Density at km0 and SPL at km22 (Sound Pressure Level). The timestamps for both don't match as the measurements are taken 22 kilometers apart. The idea here is to track a water batch (Density ~1) at km22 watching the SPL levels.

[This](https://cidra.sharefile.com/d/sd5aa8d13c314fdca) is the data frame I'm using.

As you can see there are 5 variables. This is what I have so far after importing the data into R:

```
# Melting the data
mydata2 <- melt(mydata, id = c('TIMESTAMP'))

# Create the faceted plot
ggplot(mydata2, aes(TIMESTAMP, value)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(variable~., scale  = "free_y")
```

Which plots this:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Can I only plot the variables DENSITY and SPL from the original data frame (mydata)?
2. If I have to create a new molten data frame (mydata2), how can I only plot the variable DENSITY and SPL (without deleting the other variables)?

I hope I've made myself clear, if not please let me know how can I improve my question.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can pass `measure.vars` to `melt`. see `?melt.data.frame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `subset()` inside `ggplot()` call to subset data you need to plot. In your particular case:

```
ggplot(data=subset(mydata2,variable %in% c("DENSITY","SPL")), aes(TIMESTAMP, value)) + 
  geom_point() + facet_grid(variable~., scale  = "free_y")
```

Comment: You don't have to change mydata2 (it's the same melted dataframe as in your code).

Comment: @Didziz Elferts Can I create a similar plot using only the mydata data frame?

Comment: @ChelseaE No, for faceting you need melted dataframe as in mydata2. For ggplot2 it is almost always better to use melted dataframes in long format.